# Best software for editable encrypted password file

Tags: encryption, password-manager

I am looking for a simple, portable, and cross-platform way to keep an encrypted password file.

Right now I'm using https://encipher.it/ and emailing myself the encrypted text whenever I change it.   It's not great because I'm just trusting that the website is doing everything client-side.

Things I would like

- Ability to easily edit the file and re-encrypt when done.
- Being required to enter a password every time I view or edit the file.
- Not to have to create a disk image or anything.
- No accounts or anything that I could get locked out of.
- Easy sync to/from cloud.
- Ability to edit from multiple devices (android, macbook, linux computer, etc).
- Bonus would be to have [Deniable Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deniable_encryption)

Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 1):

[KeePass](https://keepass.info) is a free open source password manager. It support a lot of things you ask for. It keep all the information in one small, easy transferable file. Here is list of most of the futures you can find in this software:

- Strong Security
- Multiple User Keys
- Portable and No Installation Required, Accessibility
- Export To TXT, HTML, XML and CSV Files
- Import From Many File Formats
- Easy Database Transfer
- Support of Password Groups
- Time Fields and Entry Attachments
- Auto-Type, Global Auto-Type Hot Key and Drag&Drop
- Intuitive and Secure Clipboard Handling
- Searching and Sorting
- Multi-Language Support
- Strong Random Password Generator
- Plugin Architecture